# "The system cannot find the path specified" when performing a Mercurial merge

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm fairly sure this isn't a bug in Mercurial, but I have a merge I am attempting to perform that seems to be impossible to complete. The merge is rather large - consisting of about a weeks' worth of work that has occurred since I last brought my branch up to date. There are a number of conflicts as you might imagine but here's the error message that totally stops the merge from happening.

> moving MyApp.Data/Entities/File.cs to MyApp.Data/Documents/File.cs
>   abort: C:\Users\stever\Documents\MyApp\MyApp.Data/Entities/File.cs: The system cannot find the path specified

It seems obvious to me that it would not be possible to find MyApp.Data/Entities/File.cs because it was only just moved. The really strange thing however is that MyApp.Data/Documents/File.cs is not actually part of the changeset I am trying to merge in. Perhaps an instruction to move the file was committed but the file itself was removed?

The working directory is then left in an uncommitted state with a number of changed files but no pending merges.

I've found this error message in relation to long paths but my path length is only about 120 characters, and there are longer paths specified further up in the log.

I am using TortoiseHG 3.2.1 on Windows 8.1.

**Update:** I have now resolved this problem, but not in a clever way. I added another commit to the second branch that added this extra file and then performed the merge which worked correctly. However, I'm not sure what knock-on effects this could have so I would appreciate a better solution. Just when I think I know Mercurial it turns out I really only know about 0.5% of it.

Comment: Without being to reproduce the problem, it is difficult to guess what might be the problem. Lets try one in a million question: are you perhaps working on an open source project, so you can provide links in order for us to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Regrettably not; if it were an open source project I would have provided the URL. I will try and find a way to replicate the issue and file a bug report with the Mercurial team.